# Magento Reset password not working

Tags: php, magento

I have magento 1.9.2 installed in my shop. When I click on forget password and enter email address, it send the reset link to my email, once I click on reset link it redirect to index.php/customer/account/changeforgotten/ After that I enter new password and confirm password and hit the reset password button, It refresh the same page. Does not show any error in error log as well. Could anybody help me with this issue. I search over internet could not find any solution. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Can you check source code on /customer/account/changeforgotten/ page and confirm that form action parameter points to /customer/account/resetpasswordpost/ ?

Comment: take a look in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` file and `changeForgottenAction` method, you can make some debug there. Also, try to do it from firefox if you are doing it in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento v.1.9.2.2 it is required to send a form key with the forgot password form.

In your template customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml put:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Just under the `<form action="...">` tag. Then, refresh the cache and see if the hidden input with a form key is present in the page.

Hopefully this will solve your issue :)